# how to cast a variable in xpath python

Tags: python, python-2.7, xpath, lxml, python-requests

```
from lxml import html
import requests

pagina = 'http://www.beleggen.nl/amx'
page = requests.get(pagina)
tree = html.fromstring(page.text)

aandeel = tree.xpath('//a[@title="Imtech"]/text()')
print aandeel
```

This part works, but I want to read multiple lines with different titles, is it possible to change the "Imtech" part to a variable?

Something like this, it obviously doesnt work, but where did I go wrong? Or is it not quite this easy?

```
FondsName = "Imtech"
aandeel = tree.xpath('//a[@title="%s"]/text()')%(FondsName)
print aandeel
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You were almost right:

```
variabelen = [var1,var2,var3]
for var in variabelen:
    aandeel = tree.xpath('//a[@title="%s"]/text()' % var)
```

Comment: This is what I was looking for, I assume it will also work with a dictionary?

Comment: You mean a dict instead of a list?

Comment: yes, I've got it working now, all thanks to you and a bit of improvising

Answer (score 7):

XPath allows `$variables` and lxml's `.xpath()` method allows for supplying values for those variables as keyword arguments: `.xpath('$variable', variable='my value')`

Using your example, here's how you'd do it:

```
fonds_name = 'Imtech'
aandeel = tree.xpath('//a[@title="$title"]/text()', title=fonds_name)
print(aandeel)
```

See lmxl's docs for more info: http://lxml.de/xpathxslt.html#the-xpath-method

Answer (score 4):

Almost...

```
FondsName = "Imtech"
aandeel = tree.xpath('//a[@title="%s"]/text()'%FondsName)
print aandeel
```