# Error in using a variable in xpath in Python Selenium

Tags: python, selenium

I have an xpath which works perfectly fine. Here is my code:

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//div[contains(text(), "aots-cm")]').click()
```

But "aots-cm" is a hard coded value. I want to pass a variable instead of hard coded value.

```
assetId = ("aots-cm")
my_var = ("'//div[contains(text()," + " " + '"' + assetId+ '"' +  ")]'")
print (my_var)
=== > '//div[contains(text(), "aots-cm")]' ==> looks ok to me
driver.find_element_by_xpath(my_var).click()
```

There is error message 
Given xpath expression "'//div[contains(text(), "aots-cm")]'" is invalid: TypeError: The expression cannot be converted to return the specified type.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to cast a variable in xpath python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26297410/how-to-cast-a-variable-in-xpath-python)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When you add the `()` around the string in `my_var` you make it a tuple of length 1, and it needs to be a string. I would do it like so.

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//div[contains(text(), "{}")]'.format(assetID)).click()
```

Answer (score 1):

@SuperStew's answer is the best **Pythonic** way. Having said that you can also opt for an alternative by creating a function to accept a `String` which will be passed from the `main()` function as follows :

```
def click_me(myString):
        driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//div[.='" + myString + "']").click()
```

Now, you can call this function with the required `String` argument whenever and wherever required as follows :

```
click_me("aots-cm")
```